# python glob.glob - how to find a specific file (or a list of files) without knowing how deep it in in subdirs?

Tags: python, linux, networking, glob

Right now, I use subprocess to invocate `find` which does the job fine, but I am after a pythonic way of doing things.

here's the current code:

```
cmd = "find /sys/devices/pci* | grep '/net/' |grep address"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

In the output I receive the following list:

```
[root@host1 ~]# find /sys/devices/pci* |grep '/net/'|grep 'address'
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:00.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:00.0/0000:08:00.0/net/eth0/address
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:00.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:01.0/0000:09:00.0/net/eth1/address
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:00.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:02.0/0000:0a:00.0/net/rename4/address
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:00.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:03.0/0000:0b:00.0/net/eth3/address
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:00.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:04.0/0000:0c:00.0/net/eth4/address
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:00.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:05.0/0000:0d:00.0/net/eth5/address
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:00.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:06.0/0000:0e:00.0/net/eth6/address
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:00.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:07.0/0000:0f:00.0/net/eth7/address
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:00.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:08.0/0000:10:00.0/net/eth8/address
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:00.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:09.0/0000:11:00.0/net/eth9/address
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:00.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:0a.0/0000:12:00.0/net/eth10/address
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:00.0/0000:06:00.0/0000:07:0b.0/0000:13:00.0/net/eth11/address
```

Now, if I do `glob.glob('/sys/devices/pci*/*/*/*/*/*/*/net/')` I do get a list of directories, and I can even look for the files, but it definitely seems to take longer than `find` does, even through subprocess. Moreover, the set of results is huge, and I can't know ahead whether the specific hosts' architecture will have the same directory structure, so I don't know how many asterisks to enter in `glob.glob()`.

My question is, how can I repeat the behaviour the simple `find | grep` command achieves, or, alternatively, if there is a  nicer way of finding all the MACs of all the NICs a host has, whether active or not (I'm looking for specific MAC patterns here)

EDIT: Shouldn't have used glob, os.walk seems to be doing the job:

```
>>> for root, dirs, names in os.walk('/sys/devices/'):
...     if 'address' in names and 'pci' in root:
...         f = open(str(root + '/address'), 'r')
...         mac = f.readlines()[0].strip()
...         f.close()
...         print mac
...         eth = root.split('/')[-1]
...         print eth
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked out os.walk()?

```
import os
for root, dirs, names in os.walk(path):
    ...
```

http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk

From the above link, here is a way to skip over certain directories:

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('python/Lib/email'):
    print root, "consumes",
    print sum(getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files),
    print "bytes in", len(files), "non-directory files"
    if 'CVS' in dirs:
        dirs.remove('CVS')  # don't visit CVS directories
```

Comment: If you know that some subdirectories doesn't contain the file(s) you are looking for, you can `del` them from the `dirs` variable so it won't be processed. For example, you could skip all the directories not matching `/sys/devices/pci*` if it gets otherwise expensive.

Comment: hi Philippe,  can you please provide an example for this `del` usage? I obviously am not a very experienced pythonista, yet :)

Comment: Ah! So I can tamper with the dirs on the fly, and it affects the search! This is perfect, thanks